# Passing struct to functions and modifying it in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

So I have the following code:

```
struct list_el{
   int val;
   struct list_el * next;
};

typedef struct list_el item;

...
```

I have a list of values in `prev` and with this list I want to use this list to analyze it. I mean, it is a list of `int`s so every `int` means a token. It is a syntactical analyzer.

So I want to analyze it step by step. Something like this:

```
if (program(prev)){
    printf("SINTAX OK.\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}else{
    printf("Error.\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

And `program`:

```
int program(item *list){
   if (list->val == 11) list = list->next;
   else return 0;
   while (list->val == 13) datEst(list);
   if (list->val == 12) list = list->next;
   else return 0;
   if (list == NULL) return 1;
   else return 0;    
}
```

And `datEst`:

```
int datEst(item *list){
    if(list->val == 13){
        list = list->next;
        return 1;
    }else return 0;
}
```

So the thing is it works properly without using `while (list->val == 13) datEst(list);`, but when it has to use `datEst` it fails.

I suppose it is a matter of deepness but I'm not sure.

Any clue or advice? Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: the function being invoked is 'program' but the function name is 'programa'.  the function programa should probably check the parameter for NULL as a first step, before referencing offsets from it.

Comment: That was a mistake, but in my code it is ok. Same names, haha.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (list->val == 13) datEst(list);
```

stays in an infinite loop if the `list->val` is equal to `13`.

You are modifying `list` in `datEst` but that's just a local copy of the variable. It doesn't change what `list` points to in the `program`.

Possible solution:

```
while (list && list->val == 13) list = list->next;
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I know that, the thing is I want to modify prev, not the local copy. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by modify prev?

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to change

```
  int datEst(item *list){
    if(list->val == 13){
       list = list->next;
       return 1;
    }else return 0;
  }
```

into

```
  int datEst(item& list){
    if(list.val == 13){
       list = list.next;
       return 1;
    }else return 0;
  }
```

This would turn `list` into an argument passed by reference, which might be what you want.

Comment: this is C, not C++, so a reference variable is not available

Comment: Thank you for your comment but this does not seem to work. Actually I have compilation errors. Is there anything else I should change in my code?

Comment: My apologies. Passing by reference is not in C. I'm not sure why I thought it was.

Answer (score 0):

c does not have references but it does have pointers to pointers

```
int datEst(item ** listRef)
{
     item* list = *listRef;  // dereference the first pointer to get a local list

    if(list->val == 13)
    {
        list = list->next;

        *listRef = list;         // store the new list value
        return 1;
    }else return 0;
}
```

and would need to be called like this :

```
while (list != NULL && list->val == 13)
{
    datEst( &list );
}
```